# URL for restricted sharing in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, privacy, file-sharing

When I click **Get a shareable link** for a file or folder in Google Drive, it automatically switches the privacy settings to **Anyone with a link can view**.

Is there a way to obtain a URL link to the file or folder but still keep the privacy settings of **only specific people can access**?